# Excel VBA applying filters for specific row items

Tags: excel, vba

The data shows the salary doctors corresponding to their post code. 
i have to display the sum of salary of male and female doctors aged between 25-30 having post code starting SW15 or SW16. There are 1000 post codes, but only data for post code starting with SW15 and SW16  is to be shown. I have done this but not getting the required output .

```
Dim pvItem As PivotItem

For Each pvtitem In Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotRow("POSTCODE").PivotItems
    If (pvItem.Name = "SW15" Or pvItem.Name = "SW16") Then
        pvItem.Visible = True
    Else
        pvItem.Visible = False
    End If
 Next pvtitem
```

Answer (score 0):

To test whether the name of a pivot item starts with either SW15 or SW16, try...

```
If (Left(pvItem.Name, 4) = "SW15" Or Left(pvItem.Name, 4) = "SW16") Then
```

By the way, PivotRow is not a member of the PivotTable object.  Also, you have a couple of spelling mistakes.  In any case, here's another way...

```
Dim pvItem As PivotItem

With Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("POSTCODE")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each pvItem In .PivotItems
        If (Left(pvItem.Name, 4) <> "SW15" And Left(pvItem.Name, 4) <> "SW16") Then
            pvItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pvItem
End With
```

Hope this helps!